# Wrong use of Javascript setInterval()

Tags: javascript

I have a function called using `setInterval` of JavaScript, which in some scenarios is called multiple times without the interval gap defined (I suspect this is because the intervals are not cleared properly and I'm creating multiple intervals, but I'm not sure).

I can not reproduce the problem locally.

The code uses [Twirl](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaTemplates) but it's basically JS:

```
    function refreshCheckInRequests() {

        if (interval) { // If there is an interval running stop it.
            clearInterval(interval);
        }

        jsRoutes.controllers.ExtranetSecuredController.findPendingCheckInRequests("@gymId").ajax({ // Ajax call using Play Framework

            success: function (data) {

                $("#checkin-request-container").html(data);
                addRowListeners()
            },
            error: function (data) {

                if (data.status == 401) {

                    errorSwitchGym("@Messages("extranet.switch.gym")");
                    //location.reload();
                }
                else {
                    unexpectedError(data)
                }
            },
            complete: function() {

                interval = initInterval(); // At the end of the call init the interval again
            }
        });
    }

    function initInterval() {
        return setInterval(function () { refreshCheckInRequests(); }, 
    20000);
    }

    var interval;
    refreshCheckInRequests();

    $("#checkin-request-refresh").click(function (event) {

                refreshCheckInRequests();
                event.preventDefault();
            });
```

I could use `setTimeout` instead because at the end, I always call `refreshCheckInRequests` once, I stop the interval, and at the end I create a new one.

If I use timeout I have to call again my function at the end of the execution of the callback of timeout (like I'm doing right now). If something goes wrong, my callback will never be called again.

Anyway, I would like to know what's going on here. Am I missing something? Am I doing something wrong? Any suggestions?

Comment: What is `initInterval`?

Comment: @CertainPerformance updated

Comment: instead of `return` assign to `interval` variable.

Comment: `complete` callback is guaranteed to be called. So can use `setTimeout` without a fear of loop being stopped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're clearing the current interval every time `refreshCheckInRequests` is called, but there is a delay between when `refreshCheckInRequests` is called and the new interval is assigned. Because `refreshCheckInRequests` also runs when an element is clicked, the following scenario could result in an unterminated interval:

1. User clicks, current interval is cleared, asynchronous `findPendingCheckInRequests` runs
2. User clicks again, no interval currently exists (nothing to clear), another asynchronous `findPendingCheckInRequests` runs
3. Response from first `findPendingCheckInRequests` comes back. `complete` handler runs, `interval` is assigned to the new interval
4. Response from second `findPendingCheckInRequests` comes back. `complete` handler runs, `interval` is assigned to the new interval *over* the old interval

The first created interval remains running, but there no longer exists a reference to it, so that first interval continues repeating forever.

So, try clearing the interval *at the moment* you reassign `interval`, ensuring that every new interval will always clear the old one, if an old one is running:

```
complete: function() {
  clearInterval(interval);
  interval = initInterval();
}
```